# Does someone know a C compiler which does not rely on gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, portability

I am trying to see if my code is portable among many compilers other than GCC and absolutely other than compiler that accept the GNU C dialects, because I am using a lot of extensions and attributes.
For attributes I have used the operator `_has_attribute` to check if the attribute's features are implemented, but for extensions it is not so quite easy.
So I need to do some test to the program's portability to see what I should modify.
Does someone know a compiler which does not rely on gcc?

Comment: One key area is where it says implementation defined in the C spec, there is an increasing amount of bad code that relies on GCC's implementation that is not portable and wont be found with _has_attribute.  bitfields, structs, unions in particular.  And dont expect to find these in the compilers documentation (other than the source code), gotta read the language spec they claim to conform to and then do experiments.

Comment: Yes there are other compilers out there, should be easy to find a number of them.  While true a bunch are starting to just be modified variations or wrappers around gcc, making this problem worse.

Comment: also note a purist will say the only C standard is the current C standard.  Not all toolchains re-tool for every release of the standard ever time.  Depending on what your target is you may never see an up to the current standard compiler for that target, but may still be required to use such a tool professionally.  a tool is not going to tell you compliance/portability.  A lot of it comes from experience, dont use ghee whiz features of the language (no directives/pragmas is a good start, either dont use structs/unions/bitfields at all or use them properly, careful with pointers, etc).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C_compilers

Comment: @MarcGlisse Nice to see Wikipedia mention that MSVC made it to C89 compliance.  ;-)

Comment: Tool recommendations are off-topic here. Pretty much all compilers that aren't gcc fit the bill. For x86 clang and icc are the most well-known. There's also Embarcadero and Visual Studio, though the latter doesn't follow standard C.

Answer (score 3):

One such compiler is [Oracle Developer Studio](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/developerstudio/overview/index.html).  That actually provides some very good tools, especially for multithreaded process analysis.

You can also use GCC's `-std`, `-Wpedantic`, and `-pedantic-errors` options to check for non-portable code.  See [**3.4 Options Controlling C Dialect**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.3.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options).  For example `gcc -std=c11 -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors ...` should allow only strictly-compliant C11 code to pass without warning or error.  You can add `Werror` also, to cause errors on any warning.

Comment: Maybe even `... -Wpedantic-errors ...`

Comment: @pmg Added.  Thanks.

Comment: suncc (Oracle Developer Studio) supports a number of gcc extensions nowadays.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I know.  I'm not sure how `gcc`-ified it's become, though, so I left that out.

Comment: @pmg There also appears to be a `-Werror=pedantic` option for GCC.  It's mentioned on https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.3.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options, but not really explained otherwise.  It seems to be a limit on `Werror`, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are some compilers not based on gcc, such as clang or MSVC, but I think you are not approaching this problem from the best perspective.

There is a standard that specifies exactly what features are included in the language (i.e. what we call *portable*) and there are compiler documentations which present what features are *extensions* to the language. You should approach this problem by reading the documentations available and understanding if the features are actually portable or nor. And if they are not, how common is for other compilers to implement them.

Comment: I might not approached the problem using such words correctly, because I am not a native English speaker. But thanks for your tips, I learned some new English words too

Comment: Testing portability via other compilers/version does help shake out differences of C spec interpretation.  Newer features like `_Generic` often are complaint, or nearly so, but the spec allows enough wiggle room (lack of specificity) for different functionality.